# php delete directory and files under this directory older than 31 days?

Tags: php, file, delete-file

How to delete directory and files under this directory older than 31 days?

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__).'/../../mongo'; //path is right, no error warning
  if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ((time()-filectime($path.'/'.$file)) < 31*24*60*60) {
            unlink($path.'/'.$file);
        }
    }
  }
```

My code delete nothing. Here is some screenshort, it still contain some directories.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure what you unlink is correct ? Do the full path is correct when you `echo` it ?

Comment: @tsabz, yes, I can print them out. like: `E:\www/../../mongo/.` `E:\www/../../mongo/..` `E:\www/../../mongo/.gitignore` `E:\www/../../mongo/bson.c`...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that these directories are not existing :)

Answer (score 0):

Use DirectoryIterator, Luke.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php